# Viewing the contents of previous commits in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

- In Xcode when I go to Organizer -> Repositories I can see the list of
  all the commits I've made sorted by dates.
- For any commit, I can expand the viewing area by clicking the disclosure triangle to the
  left.
- This shows me the list of file that were
  added/modified/deleted in that commit.
- I can click any file in his
  view to open the versions editor and view the diferences from my
  working copy.

Now here's what I'd like to do: I'd like to do is **view the contents of files that I deleted in this commit**. Is there a way I can view them from within Xcode? It looks like one can only see which files were modified and what those modifications were. There seems to be no way to view contents of deleted files.

Can someone prove me wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GIT, for Subversion the situation is as follows.

Deleted files are handled differently in Subversion and thus most clients have trouble getting information about them, so does XCode. The only way I see is to use the command line. You need to know at which revision the file was deleted. Let's say this number is 101, so at 100 it existed yet.

Open a terminal and type:

```
svn log https://myserver/myrepos/mypath/DeletedFile.m@100
svn cat https://myserver/myrepos/mypath/DeletedFile.m@100
```

You can even perform diffs. To compare revisions 85 and 90:

```
svn diff -r 85:90 https://myserver/myrepos/mypath/DeletedFile.m@100
```